# How to make dynamic tabpanels according to number of files uploaded and render a complicated Table within the tab

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny, tabpanel

I am working on an app where the user can upload either one file or multiple files of individual-level data to get analyzed.
So far if the user uploads multiple files the app combines all the files in one dataset and analyzes all of them combined. I have different outputs 2 tables and a graph.
What I am struggling to do is when the user uploads multiple files I want to keep the compiled result but I want to add dynamic tabs to each box according to the number of files uploaded to present the table/graph for that file alone.

I added a checkbox so the user checks it if they are uploading multiple files. The idea was to write an observeEvent code to insert tabs according to the number of files being uploaded, that code got complicated because I had to put the renderTable chunk within it, and it is not working.

So my question is, is there a better way of doing what I am trying to do? and If my idea makes sense what is wrong with my code and why isn't it working? Thank you

Here is a sample of the code;

```r
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyr)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "Treatment and Care Cascade",
                    titleWidth = 300),

    #Sidebar contents (tabs)
    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("HIV Cascade", tabName = "hiv")
        )),

    #Main panel for displaying outputs
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            #First tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "hiv",
                    h2("HIV Treatment and Care Cascade"),
                    fluidRow(
                        #Input: Select a file for hcv data
                        box(fluidRow(
                            box(fileInput("dt_hiv","Choose CSV File",
                                          multiple = TRUE,
                                          accept = c("text/csv",
                                                     "text/comma-separated-values,tesxt/plain",".csv")),width = 12,solidHeader = TRUE, height = 75),


                            #Input: Checkbox if file has header                           
 box(checkboxInput("multiplehiv", "Uploading multiple files",TRUE),width = 3,solidHeader = TRUE, height = 50)), width = 12, height = 255),

                        #Outputs
                        tabBox(id = "hivcasbox", tabPanel(id = "tab1", title ="HIV Cascade",tableOutput("hivcascade"))),
                        box(tableOutput("hivCascadeduration"), title = "HIV Cascade - duration", solidHeader = TRUE)
                        ))
            )))

server <- function(input, output){

    #Combining the datasets together
    dthiv <- reactive({req(input$dt_hiv)
        rbindlist(lapply(input$dt_hiv$datapath, fread, header = input$hivheader, quote = input$hivquote, sep = input$hivsep),
                  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
    })

    #The analysis chunk
    cascade_hiv <- reactive({dthiv() %>% summarize("Diagnosed" = sum(hiv_posresult,na.rm = T),
                                                   "Linkage to care" = sum(linkagetocare_hiv,na.rm = T))})

    cascade_hiv1 <- reactive({as.data.frame(t(cascade_hiv()))})


    Percentage <- reactive({(round((cascade_hiv1()$V1*100/cascade_hiv1()$V1[1]),1))}) 
    cascade_hiv3 <- reactive({cbind(cascade_hiv1(),Percentage())})
    cascade_hiv4 <- reactive({cascade_hiv3() %>% rename(Total = V1, Percentage = "Percentage()")})



    output$hivcascade <- renderTable({

      cascade_hiv5 <- as.data.frame(cascade_hiv4())
            rownames(cascade_hiv5) <- c("Diagnosed","Linkage to care")
        cascade_hiv5},include.rownames = TRUE)



    observeEvent(input$multiplehiv, {

         for (i in 1:length(input$dt_hiv$datapath)) {
             insertTab(inputId = "hivcasbox",
                       tabPanel(paste("Region",i), renderTable({

                           dthiv_r <- input$dt_hiv$datapath[i] %>% summarize("Diagnosed" = sum(hiv_posresult,na.rm = T),
                                                                             "Linkage to care" = sum(linkagetocare_hiv,na.rm = T))

                           cascade_hiv1_r <- as.data.frame(t(dthiv_r))

                           Percentage_r <- round((cascade_hiv1_r$V1*100/cascade_hiv1_r$V1[1]),1)
                           cascade_hiv3_r <- cbind(cascade_hiv1_r,Percentage_r)
                           cascade_hiv4_r <- cascade_hiv3_r %>% rename(Total = V1, Percentage = "Percentage_r")

                           cascade_hiv5_r <- as.data.frame(cascade_hiv4_r)
                           rownames(cascade_hiv5_r) <- c("Diagnosed","Linkage to care")

                          cascade_hiv5_r},include.rownames = FALSE)),
                       target = "tab1")
         }

     })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

<sup>Created on 2019-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

the app runs but when I check the multiple files box, no tabs get inserted

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the above code to work but I found another one that works using "str and eval(parse(text = str))", 
however, it is not the most elegant or concise code, so I would appreciate it if someone has a better way of doing it. Thank you!

```
ibrary(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyr)
library(shinyjs)
library(data.table)

ui <- dashboardPage(

    dashboardHeader(title = "Treatment and Care Cascade",
                    titleWidth = 300),

    dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenu(
            menuItem("HIV Cascade", tabName = "hiv")
        )),

    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            #First tab content
            tabItem(tabName = "hiv",
                    h2("HIV Treatment and Care Cascade"),
                    fluidRow(
                        #Input: Select a file for hcv data
                        box(fluidRow(
                            box(fileInput("dt_hiv","Choose CSV File",
                                          multiple = TRUE,
                                          accept = c("text/csv",
                                                     "text/comma-separated-values,tesxt/plain", ".csv")),width = 12,solidHeader = TRUE, height = 75),

                            #actionButton("multiplehiv", "Add 'Dynamic' tab"),
                            #Input: Checkbox if file has header
                            box(checkboxInput("multiplehiv", "Uploading multiple files",FALSE),
                                width = 3,solidHeader = TRUE, height = 50)
                            ), width = 12, height = 255),

                        #Outputs
                        uiOutput("tabs")
                        ))
            )))
server <- function(input, output){

    dthiv <- reactive({req(input$dt_hiv)
        rbindlist(lapply(input$dt_hiv$datapath, fread),
                  use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
    })

    cascade_hiv <- reactive({dthiv() %>% summarize("Diagnosed" = sum(hiv_posresult,na.rm = T),
                                                   "Linkage to care" = sum(linkagetocare_hiv,na.rm = T))})

    cascade_hiv1 <- reactive({as.data.frame(t(cascade_hiv()))})


    Percentage <- reactive({(round((cascade_hiv1()$V1*100/cascade_hiv1()$V1[1]),1))}) 
    cascade_hiv3 <- reactive({cbind(cascade_hiv1(),Percentage())})
    cascade_hiv4 <- reactive({cascade_hiv3() %>% rename(Total = V1, Percentage = "Percentage()")})
        n_files <- reactive({length(input$dt_hiv$datapath)})
output$tabs <- renderUI({


        if (input$multiplehiv == 1) {

            str <- "tabBox(id = 'hivcasbox',
                   tabPanel(id = 'taball', title = 'HIV Cascade' ,tableOutput('hivcascade')),"
            for (i in 1:n_files()) {str <- paste0(str, "tabPanel(id = paste('tab', ",i,") , title = paste('Data', ",i,") , tableOutput('hivcascader_",i,"')),")}

            str <- gsub(",$",")",str)

            eval(parse(text = str)) 
            }

 else {
            tabBox(id = "hivcasbox", 
                   tabPanel(id = "tab1", title = "HIV Cascade",tableOutput("hivcascade")))
            }
    })


                output$hivcascade <- renderTable({
                    cascade_hiv5 <- as.data.frame(cascade_hiv4())
                    rownames(cascade_hiv5) <- c("Diagnosed","Linkage to care")
                    cascade_hiv5},include.rownames = TRUE)   
 dt_files <- reactive({lapply(input$dt_hiv$datapath[1:n_files()],read.csv)})


                observe({
                    for (i in 1:n_files())
                    {str1 <- paste0("dthiv_r_",i,"<- reactive({dt_files()[[",i,"]] %>% summarize('Diagnosed' = sum(hiv_posresult,na.rm = T),
                                                                       'Linkage to care' = sum(linkagetocare_hiv,na.rm = T))})
                    cascade_hiv1_r_",i,"<- reactive({as.data.frame(t(dthiv_r_",i,"()))})
                    Percentage_r_",i,"<- reactive({round((cascade_hiv1_r_",i,"()$V1*100/cascade_hiv1_r_",i,"()$V1[1]),1)})
                    cascade_hiv3_r_",i," <- reactive({cbind(cascade_hiv1_r_",i,"(),Percentage_r_",i,"())})
                    cascade_hiv4_r_",i,"<- reactive({cascade_hiv3_r_",i,"() %>% rename(Total = V1, Percentage = 'Percentage_r_",i,"()')})")
                eval(parse(text = str1))}
                    for (i in 1:n_files()) {
                        str2 <- paste0("output$hivcascader_",i," <- renderTable({
                    cascade_hiv5_r_",i," <- as.data.frame(cascade_hiv4_r_",i,"())
                    rownames(cascade_hiv5_r_",i,") <- c('Diagnosed','Linkage to care')
                    cascade_hiv5_r_",i,"},include.rownames = TRUE)")
                        eval(parse(text = str2))}
                })
}                  
shinyApp(ui, server)
```